# Export Keynote slides to images with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, keynote

I have Keynote slides and I want automatically export them to images for further uploading to server using AppleScript. I've tried to manage it:

```
tell application "Keynote"
    set doc to open "full-path-to-.key"
    save doc -- this line didn't help
    export doc to file "full-path-to-folder" as slide images
end tell
```

This script terminates with

```
error "Keynote got an error: The document “...” could not be exported as “full-path-to-folder”. Your most recent changes might be lost." number 6
```

Why?

Comment: Could replace the dummy placeholders with the actual paths you use for your file and folder ?  It's not a security risk in any way.  The format of your file paths, its location on your drive, or a character in the filename could provoke an error that is being misreported.  This happens in _QuickTime_ very regularly, and wouldn't surprise me if it started to happen in other Apple-made software.

Comment: Have a look at: [AppleScript and Keynote: Exporting Documents](https://iworkautomation.com/keynote/document-export.html) - I tested the Export Slides to Images script with Keynote, version 8.1 (5683), on macOS High Sierra and it worked rather nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a closer look at [this exporting documents samples](https://iworkautomation.com/keynote/document-export.html) and ran into a problem with referencing a folder I want export my slides to. Then I've found [that thing](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ReferenceFilesandFolders.html) about it with a sample

```
set thePath to alias "Macintosh HD:Users:yourUserName:Desktop:"
```

So this one works properly:

```
tell application "Keynote"
     set doc to open "/absolute/path/to/slides.key"
     export doc to alias "Macintosh HD:Users:myUserName:further:path" as slide images with properties {image format:PNG}
end tell
```